# vb.net and crystal report responding so slow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, report

Hi good day can anyone help me for my project i have created a vb.net application that produced a 473052 record in the report and i take 3-5 minutes before the report loaded here's my code:

---my function

```
     Public Function staffbyyear(ByVal dates As String) As DataTable
    Dim db = New database
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    With db
        .sqlStr = "SELECT date, attendant, subtotal FROM transactions where year(date)= '" & dates & "' and finish = 1" 'query string
        .sqlDa.SelectCommand = .sqlcm(.sqlStr, .connect) 'execute command
        .sqlDa.Fill(.sqlDt) 'get results and store in sqldt
        .close()
    End With

    dt = db.sqlDt

    Return dt
End Function
```

--to fill my report

```
      Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
      Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
      Private rptstr as string
      Private Sub fillreportstaffbyyear(ByVal d As String)
       Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
       Dim rptPath = Application.StartupPath.Remove(Application.StartupPath.IndexOf("bin"), Len(Application.StartupPath) - Application.StartupPath.IndexOf("bin"))
       cryRpt.Load(rptPath & "reportstaffbyyear.rpt") '
       cryRpt.SetDataSource(staffbyyear(cmbyear.Text))
       '---modified here
       crviewer.crv1.ReportSource = cryRpt
       rptstr = vbNullString


End Sub
```

--to show the report

```
     Private Sub ButtonX5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonX5.Click
        Dim strname As String = cmbyear.Text.Trim
        fillreportstaffbyyear(strname)
        crviewer.Show()
     End sub
```

Comment: In which part are your experiencing the "slow" behavior? Have you checked whether your query is returning the needed rows immediately?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b in the part that the record display in the crystal report viewer and filling record to the report hope you can help me

Comment: How long does your query take to retrieve all those rows?

Comment: it takes 2-3 mins and if you click on the next page another 1 minute will take to load

Comment: Well it must be the sheer number of rows. Do you really need to generate all the 400K+ rows all at once?

Comment: i need your opinion what is the best way because this report is annual report of total sales?

Comment: There are suggestions from these posts [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?353212-RESOLVED-Crystal-reports-huge-report-how-to-speed-it-up) [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?353212-RESOLVED-Crystal-reports-huge-report-how-to-speed-it-up)

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b all the suggestion you gave it still the same

Comment: Maybe you can generate your report by category or you can implement some form of filtering on your query. No one will read a 7000+ page report.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b ok thank you :)